# How can I use Apache Tika to extract css and html text

Tags: apache-tika

I want to use apache tika to extract html text and css class names so that I can build a poi spreadsheet. I can get the text but how do I extract css class names?

Thank You In Advance  ...

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a custom handler. If you override the startElement method you'll have access to the html attributes. Inheriting from BodyContentHandler should be pretty simple as a starting point. If the element you're targeting isn't getting mapped and you're not getting it passed into startElement you'll need to tell the ParseContext to let it through, by either using the IdentityHtmlMapper or writing your own mapper.

Answer (score 0):

You could run Tika from command line
java -jar tika-app.jar -h [file|port...]
(-h or --html is an option that gives the Output of HTML content)

You could also do it programmatically by using the html parser:

```
Parser parser = new HtmlParser();
```

Thats not enough since the HTML parser first transforms the incoming HTML document to wellformed XHTML and then maps the included elements to a “safe” subset. The default
mapping drops things such as  and  elements that don’t affect the
text content of the HTML page and applies other normalization rules. This default
mapping produces good results in most use cases, but sometimes a client wants more
direct access to the **original** HTML markup. The IdentityHtmlMapper class can be
used to achieve this:

```
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(HtmlMapper.class, new IdentityHtmlMapper());
```

Finally you can get your content by calling the *parse* method:

```
parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
```

Hope this helps a bit. :)